# A set of positive integers that contains every difference?

Tags: number-theory

Can we find a set of positive integers that contain every distance exactly once? What I mean is, for each positive integer $k$ there is exactly one pair of points $x$,$y$ in the set with $ |x-y| = k $

Been stuck on this for a while. Tried considering the powers of 2, but that doesn't quite work.

Comment: my first thought is $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}:=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ - but i do not have the time to check it now. (my idea was to at least make each distance unique)

Comment: @Max this is the same thing as the powers of 2...